# Make a copy of state to edit it indirectly in children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm setting state in the parent component, then passing it as props to a child component. In the child, I would like to make a copy of that state object (received through props) to edit without updating the original state object yet. I will then display that information in the current child component and send the updated state object back to the parent to update the original state object. The now updated parent state would then be used to display information in other child elements.

In child component - where 'this.props.shifts' is the passed down state from the parent:

```
this.dowCopy = { ...this.props.dow };
this.state = {
    dowCopy: this.dowCopy
}

addTempShift = (day) => {
    const emptyShift = {arbitraryData};
    const dowCopyCopy = {...this.state.dowCopy};
    dowCopyCopy[day].shifts.push(emptyShift);
    this.setState({ dowCopy: dowCopyCopy })
}
```

Everything works as intended, but when I set state here in the child component, it's also updating state in the parent. It was my understanding that the spread operator took a copy of the state object. What am I missing?

Comment: Spread won't make copies of nested objects/arrays. Would need a recursive deep copy approach for that

Comment: What is the reason you want to edit the state in the child, then send it to parent, then send it to other children? you should be able to just edit the state in the parent and then all children could use it.

Comment: for a form. the parent holds and displays the state, and then you can open a form - which is the child - and view the state, but also edit it and view it real time without changing the parent state yet until you save it. then when saved, the parent displays it and then passes it to any other children.

Comment: i don't want to edit the form and simultaneously have state updated everywhere throughout the application. i want to edit the form with new info, view it in the form as i'm editing, and then onClick of a 'save' button update state with the new info which THEN get's displayed throughout the rest of the app.

Comment: i should mention, the form inputs are getting their value from state....is this a case for refs?

Comment: @GeorgeChanturidze

Comment: @TimothyWilburn I suppose in that case you could use refs. I've done it before to pre-populate form fields for example. If you want to trigger setState inside a child, using the data you pass through props, and call the setState based on an event in the parent, then yes - you could use a ref. This is antipattern since you're going against unidirectional flow, but I guess it's sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread syntax creates shallow copies as told by @Timothy Wilburn. So, if you change copied object property directly then you will mutate the original one. You can search for "deep copy" or you can again use spread syntax in the child component.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dow: {
      monday: { 
        shifts: [{ name: "foo" }, { name: "bar" }],
      },
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      In parent: {JSON.stringify(this.state.dow)}
      <Child dow={this.state.dow} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dowCopy: { ...this.props.dow }
  }

  addTempShift = (day) => {
    const emptyShift = { name: "baz" };
    this.setState( prevState => (
        {
            dowCopy: { ...prevState.dowCopy, [day]: { shifts: 
            [...prevState.dowCopy[day].shifts, emptyShift] } }
        }
    ))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.addTempShift( "monday");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>In Child: { JSON.stringify(this.state.dowCopy)}</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Oh, boy.

But, I agree with @George Chanturidze, you are overdoing. Do not copy the state like that. If you want to show some changed data in the Child component, then change it using this state as its prop. Then, if you want to change the parent's state, gather this data and send back to the parent with a callback and set the state there.